# how to run clang static analyzer on different target using scan-build

Tags: clang, static-analysis

I want to run clang static analyzer on different target. Here is the makefile snip:

```
CC = <path to clang folder>/build/bin/clang
.
.
.    
src/%.o: ../src/%.c
    ${CC} --target=powerpc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
```

I am trying to compile to powerpc. This is the command line and the output:

```
>> <path_to_llvm_folder>/llvm/tools/clang/tools/scan-build/scan-build --use-analyzer=<path_to_llvm_folder>/build/bin/clang make
scan-build: Using '<path_to_llvm_folder>/build/bin/clang' for static analysis
Building file: ../src/testing.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
<path to clang folder>/llvm/tools/clang/tools/scan-build/ccc-analyzer --target=powerpc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/testing.d" -MT"src/testing.o" -o "src/testing.o" "../src/testing.c"
cc1: warning: command line option "-ftarget=powerpc" is valid for Java but not for C
```

Notice that although the makefile is calling clang - I am getting gcc warning...So how do I use clang to compile the code AND for static analysis for different target ?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution. I think there is a bug in the ccc-analyzer script in the next param:

```
my %CompilerLinkerOptionMap = (
  '-Wwrite-strings' => 0,
  '-ftrapv-handler' => 1, # specifically call out separated -f flag
  '-mios-simulator-version-min' => 0, # This really has 1 argument, but always has '='
  '-isysroot' => 1,
  '-arch' => 1,
  '-m32' => 0,
  '-m64' => 0,
  '-stdlib' => 0, # This is really a 1 argument, but always has '='
  '--sysroot' => 1,
  '-target' => 1,
  '-v' => 0,
  '-mmacosx-version-min' => 0, # This is really a 1 argument, but always has '='
  '-miphoneos-version-min' => 0 # This is really a 1 argument, but always has '='
);
```

the

```
'-target' => 1,
```

needs to be

```
'--target' => 1,
```

(with double '-')...